# Configure IIS 7.5 to let only special User Agents visit the site

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

I want to restrict all visitors (by user-agents) from visiting my site, except some special user-agents (say visitors using Firefox or so...)

Please show me a way to deny all, but allow those special visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UrlRewrite` plugin to check for user-agent strings and redirect to an access restricted page.

Comment: Would you Please explain a bit more?

Comment: Simple. Install `UrlRewrite` plugin. Start IIS Manager and select the site you want. DblClick UrlWrite and click `Add rule(s)...` link. it has the "Request blocking" template you need.